# React Native failed to debug on Android device

Tags: react-native

I am getting an error while debugging on android device

```
   Could not debug. Error while executing command 'adb -s "5203f645508e343b" shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk': Command failed: adb -s "5203f645508e343b" shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
```